# CPU Load increased 4 times after upgrading to PHP5.4

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, server-load

We moved our project from 5.3.3 to PHP5.4.14 (debian).
This worked fine and the hole page loads a little bit faster. 
But: The server CPU load increased about 3 to 4 times. ( 3.38 avg currently)

What could this be?

It is an apache server running ZendFramework 1

Comment: What are you using as the Apache worker? `mpm-prefork` or 'mpm-worker` ?

Comment: it's this  package `libapache2-mod-php5 (5.4.4-14)` and as their description says: *Please note that this package ONLY works with Apache's prefork MPM, as it is not compiled thread-safe*

Comment: This is very strange. However you know that Zend is very fat. And there is no way that you have been generating more traffic?

Comment: actually we stop investigation. No results.. :( 
The load stays higher and the website feels to load faster.